# IdentityServer4 Register from a Client Application

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, identitymodel

I have created an OAUth server using IdentityServer4 together with .Net Core Identity.  It works fine for the most part.  The Startup code is as follows:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {

...
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["Settings:OAuthAddress"];
                options.ClientId = "razor_code";
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Settings:ClientSecret"];
                options.ResponseType = "id_token code";
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.Scope.Add("myapi");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.SaveTokens = true;

            });

        services.AddAuthorization();
...

    }
```

If I use the [Authorize] attribute on a page in my client site, it will automatically send the user to the OAUth server to login.  What I would like to do is to be able to use the Register and Login buttons to login the client app as well.  I figured out the Login by creating a Login page as follows:

```
[Authorize]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnGetAsync()
    {
        
        return LocalRedirect("/");

    }
}
```

If a link points to this page, the [Authorize] attribute will cause it to trigger a login on the OAuth server.  Does anyone know a better way to trigger a login?  My solution always returns to the root page of the site.  This will do, since the root page on this app is the only one without the [Authorize] attribute.  In the future that could change.

I also want the Register link to work as well.  I found this https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-prompt-create-1_0.html which indicates that the ability to go straight to the Registration page is at least in the works.  Does anyone know how to make this happen using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpeIdConnect?

I know this is technically two questions, but I am thinking the answers are related.

Comment: The login page is in the current project, or in the external project?

Comment: The login page I showed above is in the current project, but it triggers the app to go to the login page on the OAuth server.